# Failed to compile after installing formik in React (create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, formik

I installed a node server project with npm init. Within the server I installed a client side with creat-react-app. That works fine.

But, after installing formik library in the client side it fails to compile exactly when it is starting the development server.

The error is:
    
    `Module not found: 
    Can't resolve client/node_modules/babel-preset-react- 
    app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/slicedToArray
    in client/node_modules/react-dev-utils`

I am starting all (client and server sides) concurrently from the server through the concurrently library installed in the server.